# how can I get the lognormal_distribution from boost::random to act like boost::math::lognormal_distribution

Tags: c++, boost, random

I want to get a boost::variate_generator which gives me numbers distributed to the lognormal distribution according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution.

There is a distribution in boost::math that implements the formula from the wikipedia entry, but it doesn't work with the variate_generator. 
And the one from boost::random, that works with the variate_generator, is somewhat different from the above mentioned.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost/lognormal_distribution.html. Mu needs to be >0 and mu and sigma are calculated instead of just used as given.

Does someone have any idea how I can get it to work with the former formula?

EDIT

@ Howard Hinnant:

there is this init() function which gets called in the constructor. So the formula is the same, but sigma and mean get calculated this way (why I don't know):

```
   _nmean = log(_mean*_mean/sqrt(_sigma*_sigma + _mean*_mean));
  _nsigma = sqrt(log(_sigma*_sigma/_mean/_mean+result_type(1)));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be mistaken, but from inspecting the boost code, it looks to me like the boost lognormal_distribution is consistent with the wikipedia description.  The documentation would be consistent if the boost documentation dropped the N subscript from mu and sigma.

Comment: Ok, I see what you see.  I just did an update from the developer's trunk.  I don't have a specific boost version, just tip-of-trunk.  What I'm seeing is two versions of lognormal_distribution.  The one you just pointed out is commented with "this class is deprecated".  There's another implementation just above it, and in namespace boost::random.  And it looks like what you want.

Comment: I should've added.  This library is going to be standard in C++0x, and with the definition you want.  Your environment may already support std::lognormal_distribution in <random>.  Or maybe std::tr1::lognormal_distribution in <tr1/random>.